# Fail to call rest service inside sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I create a custom rest webservice using visual studio. I am able to call it with postman but fail to call it inside sharepoint-hosted app with ajax.get. Is anyone know what step I am missing in configuring sharepoint to allow custom webservice call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your rest service to enable CORS. It seems that the problem is in the service, not in SharePoint side.

For more information regarding CORS, you can visit below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api